# title overlay on hover of image

Tags: wordpress, image, overlay

I have an interesting problem, wonder if anyone can help me with a solution;

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a function in wordpress that would do the following;

If I upload an image and wrap it in a class, say 'feature', and I link it to a wordpress page, is it possible to create a function that when the image is hovered it changes the image with a color and overlays the title of the linked page? or even the image title which has been set?

Following on from this I've found this snippet;

```
$(function() {

$("img[class^='imglink']").each(function(){
    var imgTitle = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).wrap('<div class="overlay-container"></div>');
    $(this).after('<div class="overlay">'+imgTitle+'</div>');

});
});
```

But any idea how to implement it within Wordpress; Im a total novice when it comes to this;

thanks

Any help or ideas would be great

Comment: This is pretty basic CSS. You need to do some due-diligence on your own and try to get it to work yourself and then come back for help. You don't need a function for this. Could be easily done with a shortcode.

Comment: Im not sure it's possible with CSS, hence why I asked for help; I require a function to recognise that that image has a class called 'feature' or whatever, and displays the image title on hover, thats not possible with CSS only

Comment: The overlay is easy to do with CSS. You would just need to write your code for how you harness the permalink/title unless it's part of inline code in the WYSYWIG. That's pretty basic WP. It just depends how you plan on implementing (which is very broad). This isn't the place to "get" code. It's a place for code help. You'd find a lot just searching Google.

Comment: Im not 'getting code' Id like to know how it's done using a function; but thanks for your help Aibrean

Comment: You can use plain old CSS for this, no need for Javascript functions, just set up your styling using the `:hover` CSS selector.

Comment: this is where I'm getting confused; I have multiple images on the page and I want the image title to appear in the overlay, thats possible by CSS only? ahhh can i use  content: attr(title); in the CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty broad, but you can do this using CSS only, no need for Javascript. Here's something to get you started:

```css
.feature {
  height:250px;
  width:250px;
  background:url('http://placehold.it/250x250');
  position:relative;
}
  .feature:hover {
    background:red;
  }
    .feature:hover .title {
      display:block;
    }
.title {
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature">
    <div class="title">Example Title</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this APAD1, really appreciate i, but I mean the actual title you give the image in wordpress; I know how to do it by adding a title manually to the page in the div etc;

When someone uploads an image in wordpress and gives it a title in the uploader I want it to use that title, hence why it needs to be a function I think;

Comment: Still doesn't need to be a function, you just replace the hardcoded title with the Wordpress image alt text, or whatever text you're trying to get. IE `echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );`

Comment: Ahh OK - I think the problem is I don't want to hardcore the page as another user will be using the site - so he/she will add an image to the page whenever they need to and just give it a class

Comment: It wouldn't be hardcoded, the code I posted above would dynamically pull whatever text the user entered into the "alt" field of the image.

Comment: yes sorry I mean that setting up the page template; I don't want to use a pre-defined page, with areas to upload- I'd basically like this to work but only only images wrapped in a specific div class;